# can i use a transformer to run an american steam cleaner ( 120v/60hz) on a 220v/50hz

Tags: electrical, heating, low-voltage, transformer, steam

i recently purchased a steam cleaner ( sienna Luna plus) willing to use it in Algeria, but it is designed to be used in the US , the only way i found to transform 220 v 50 hz  to 110 v  ( i think continuous ) is by using an electrical transformer , can i use it normally ? if not , what should i use ? , i am hearing around that 50hz even with 120v will hurt and damage it , so i want to be more sure about it

Comment: What do you have to lose?  If I had the transformer I would try it.  Depending on the type of motor it might run at 50/60 = 83.33 % normal speed.

Comment: yes, you can...

Answer (score 1):

If the steam cleaner doesn't have motors on board you won't have issues going from 60Hz to 50Hz.
Anyway I think that will cost you less if you buy a new 220V cleaner and resell the one you have instead of buying a transformer (220V to 110V for that appliance)